# Can I have two mongodb connections in the same sails project?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I have a sails app and I am wondering if I can use two mongodb connections (two different databases on the same host with different password). I have two models and I want each one to be related to a different mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

First thing to do is add a connection to each mongoDB in the connections.js file located in the config folder and ensure they both have a different name.

For example

```
someMongodbServer1: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: 'username', //optional
    password: 'password', //optional
    database: 'your_mongo_db_name_here' //optional
},

someMongodbServer2: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: 'username', //optional
    password: 'password', //optional
    database: 'your_mongo_db_name_here' //optional
},
```

Then in each Model, you can set the respective connection. If for example you have your User data stored in one database and your images stored in another.

You can set the connection in the User model like this:

```
module.exports = {
    connection : 'someMongodbServer1',
    attributes: {...
```

And in the Images model using the other connection:

```
module.exports = {
    connection : 'someMongodbServer2',
    attributes: {...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a single Javascript runtime engine to have 2 or more client connections to MongoDB.  Each connection will have a separate connection pool to its target server.